# Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a problem on the creation of my table.

The problem lays with the creation of the foreign key/relation to antoher table.

The internet told me to check the column type and check if it was the same as the column which i was referencing to. and its the same.

Futher solutions the internet gave me didn't work So can anyone please help me?

This is the query :

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `finprodb`.`tblproject` (
  `prj_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `prj_nummer` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `prj_omschrijving` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `prj_verkoop_waarde` DECIMAL(20,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `prj_gereed` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `prj_bedr_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prj_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `prj_id_UNIQUE` (`prj_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_tblproject_tblbedrijf1_idx` (`prj_bedr_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblproject_tblbedrijf1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`prj_bedr_id` )
    REFERENCES `finprodb`.`tblbedrijf` (`bedr_id` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: If you have enough privileges, you can get the exact details by issuing a `SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON DELETE SET NULL` does not go well with `prj_bedr_id INT(11) NOT NULL`

Make the column nullable (remove the `NOT`)

Comment: Thank you very much. that was the solution.

I will mark the answer as the solution in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MYSQL well but in DB2 you can't create a relationship unless there is a unique index on the columns referenced in the parent table.
Is there a unique index on `finprodb`.`tblbedrijf` (`bedr_id` ) ?